# Custom list preference rendering issue

Tags: android, listpreference, typed-arrays

When I try to preview my preferences I get this error

> Rendering Problems java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException   at
>   android.content.res.BridgeResources.obtainTypedArray(BridgeResources.java:472)
>     at
>   com.grozeaion.www.gvicameraremotecontrol.MyListPreference.(MyListPreference.java:52)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:385)
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:432)
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:483)
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:495)
>     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:327)
>     at
>   android.preference.Preference_Delegate.inflatePreference(Preference_Delegate.java:64)
>   Copy stack to clipboard

I have created a custom list preference as follows

1. attr.xml I have

   ```
   <declare-styleable name="MyListPreference">
   <attr name="android:id" />
   <attr name="android:key" />
   <attr name="android:entries" />
   <attr name="android:entryValues" />
   <attr name="android:defaultValue" />
   <attr name="itemIco" format="integer" />
   ```
2. I have the control defined in preferences.xml

   ```
       <com.grozeaion.www.gvicameraremotecontrol.MyListPreference
       android:id="@+id/Dev2UseAs"
       android:icon="@drawable/off"
       android:key="Dev2UseAsK"
       android:summary="@string/trig_dev2m_s"
       android:title="@string/trig_dev2m_t"
       android:entries="@array/modeDevName"
       android:entryValues="@array/modeDevVal"
       android:defaultValue="0"
       custom:itemIco="@array/modeDevIco"
       />
   ```
3. The array modeDevIco looks like this

   ```
   <array name="modeDevIco">
   <item>@drawable/off</item>
   <item>@drawable/camera</item>
   <item>@drawable/flash</item>
   <item>@drawable/split</item>
   ```
4. In my custom class

   ```
   public MyListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   setLayoutResource(R.layout.my_list_value_main);
   this.context = context;
   Resources resources = context.getResources();
   preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyListPreference, 0, 0);
   try {
       crtCtrlKey = a.getString(R.styleable.MyListPreference_android_key);
       itemTitle = resources.getStringArray(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyListPreference_android_entries, 0));
       itemVal = resources.getStringArray(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyListPreference_android_entryValues, 0));
       defVal = a.getString(R.styleable.MyEditText_android_defaultValue);
       int len = itemVal.length;
       itemIco = new int[len];
       TypedArray iDs = resources.obtainTypedArray(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyListPreference_itemIco, 0));//get ID's for icons
       for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           itemIco[i] = iDs.getResourceId(i,0);
       }
       iDs.recycle();
   } finally {
       a.recycle();
   }
   ```

   }

line 52 is

```
TypedArray iDs = resources.obtainTypedArray(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyListPreference_itemIco, 0));//get ID's for icons
```

How can i fix this rendering issue? i am guessing that is because of how i am getting the icons IDs but i don't know how to do it otherwise

Answer (score 3):

I have the same rendering issue. But I am trying to get the color resources. I worked it out by isInEditMode().

```
private int[] getColorsById(int id){
    if(isInEditMode()){
        String[] s=mContext.getResources().getStringArray(id);
        int[] colors = new int[s.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++){
            colors[j] = Color.parseColor(s[j]);
        }
        return colors;
    }else{
        TypedArray typedArray=mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(id);
        int[] colors = new int[typedArray.length()];
        for (int j = 0; j < typedArray.length(); j++){
            colors[j] = typedArray.getColor(j,Color.BLACK);
        }
        typedArray.recycle();
        return colors;
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you a lot. Or you have a better way to figure it out. Just comment me.

Comment: i guess this solves the problem at hand...helped me too

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `isInEditMode` is the correct thing to use but it's not accessible from within an extended `Preference` class. I'm having this same issue and am extending an `EditTextPreference` but can't call `isInEditMode` from that class.

Comment: I don't think it's ideal, but you can use isInEditMode even in Preference class - you just need to create empty View instance and call it on it, like `boolean isEditMode = new View(context).isInEditMode();`